# website page on tablet/phone screen displays only a upper left corner ( wanted: page is minimized to fit the screen and can be zoom-ed)

Tags: html, css, web, tablet

When I open my website from a tablet or phone, it displays only a part of the page: upper right corner and it is impossible to scroll right to see all the content. I understand that for a proper display on small screens should be changes to the template and optimize it's responsivity but most websites even if they are not responsive, it displays the entire page (page is minimized  to fit the screen and can be increased). Can anyone tell me what's causing this error and what is the solution?

my website: http://kino5plus.ru

how is displayed on tablet: http://mobiletest.me/amazon_kindle_fire/1199279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make it non-responsive, start by removing the *meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" class="viewport"* in your head tag. Remove the 'overflow:hidden' on .page-box so that you can scroll the page. Then of course, you need to make changes on template structure and CSS styling across the site.